# How to make pip available to git bash command line on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I added the `pip` installation folder in my python site-packages directory to my PATH, but I can still only run it via `python -m pip` in my git bash. Just `pip` gives me `command not found`.

I looked around the `pip` directory and I don't see any binaries, so this makes sense. Yet clearly `pip` is a thing that is normally used on the command line without `python -m`. So what component am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding `C:/path/to/python/Scripts/` to PATH

Comment: Please add this as an answer so I can give you a +200 bounty. I have somehow never known about this as long as I've been using python. you just solved like four problems at once for me. God I feel dumb. Had no idea this was the explicit purpose of the Scripts folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding `C:/path/to/python/Scripts/` to PATH

There should be a pip.exe there!

Comment: Question eligible for bounty in two days. It's coming.

Comment: Wow! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

in your Anaconda directory there is a pip file in the direcctory Scripts.

add this path : C:\Users#yourname\Anaconda3\Scripts

i did the same and it was successful !!
(when i wrote pip in git bash it worked)